# Restart loop after Nvidia Zotac card install

Tags: nvidia, video

I recently installed Ubuntu on my PC and I have some problems with my zotac gt730 2gb 128bit ddr3 Nvidia card.

I tried to install the Nvidia drivers, but after that it won't start anymore, it is stuck in a restart loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. After the manufacturer's splash screen disappears when booting and right before the system starts to restart loop, bring up a text-only virtual console using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only console which shows you a login prompt. Login to the console at the login prompt with your username and password.
2. Search for installed nvidia packages.

   ```
   apt list --installed | grep nvidia
   ```
3. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt remove package-name
   ```

   Replace `package-name` with the names of the nvidia packages from the results of step 1.
4. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
5. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
6. After you reboot, install the recommended Nvidia driver with the following commands.

   ```
    sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
    sudo reboot
   ```

   The `ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available.
7. If the boot process stops and gets stuck at the purple Ubuntu logo screen, bring up a text-only virtual console using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only console which shows you a login prompt. Login to the console at the login prompt with your username and password. Run the following command to bring up the default Ubuntu login screen.

   ```
    sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up your default login screen and then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment as usual.
8. If you keep getting stuck at the same purple Ubuntu logo screen every time you boot you might want to replace the default gdm3 login display manager with the more lightweight lightdm login display manager and run the following command to enable lightdm as the new login display manager.

   ```
    sudo apt install lightdm  
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   ```

Comment: With the nouveau thing from the additional drivers works but the speed of the fun it's going crazy

Comment: And the boot process is very long

Comment: It works without the Nvidia card still

Comment: https://ibb.co/bvhxb8
https://ibb.co/drDg3o
https://ibb.co/ib6jOo
https://ibb.co/cF6UpT
https://ibb.co/mNLppT

Comment: This is what is show me after auto install

Comment: It shows the ubuntu text rendered very badly and crashes

Comment: I will try doing that

Comment: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  worked form me.