# Ubuntu 18.10 doesn't boot after installing Nvidia driver

Tags: boot, nvidia-geforce, 18.10

The new version of Ubuntu, 18.10 has a problem. I'm talking about the stable version of 18.10, not the beta version. I installed it today and it only has one kernel. When it works if it's fast, but when I rebooted it no longer started as if it had suddenly broken. This happened after installing an Nvidia GTX 390 driver. It's possible that there was a compatibility problem. My PC has an Intel Core 3.50 GHz CPU and 16GB RAM.

Comment: At GRUB, try rebooting into an older kernel.

Comment: Yes, but I installed it today and I only have one kernel

Comment: Please follow steps 1-3 of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059366/restart-loop-after-nvidia-zotac-card-install/1059367#1059367 to get Ubuntu 18.10 working again, and then we'll continue from there. Maybe you need to install a more recent version of the proprietary Nvidia driver. What model graphics card does `ubuntu-drivers devices` show?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960

Comment: If you installed a driver for a GTX 390 when you're using GTX 960, then you probably need to remove that bad driver and install the correct one.