# Black screen after reinstalling Nvidia graphics card

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login, xbmc, ipmi

After being unable to log in to the system (login loop), I followed the instructions in [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), in both the 2 most popular replies since the first one didn't work. Now after reinstalling the Nvidia graphics card using `sudo apt install nvidia-430` (which was the latest version available) and then rebooting, a black screen appears saying:

```
[  104.636774] ipmi_si IP10001:00: There appears to be no BMC at this location
```

There is a cursor in the next line, but I can't type anything and it's just stuck there. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Installing the previous one worked. But I am back to the same issue of not being able to log in. After using my credentials, a black screen appears for a second saying `rootfs:clean, 1087039/6406144 files, 9543151/25600000 blocks` and then back to the login screen

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card isn't compatible with the latest Nvidia 430 driver which isn't in the default repositories of any current Ubuntu release. You need to install an older graphics driver like nvidia-384 which is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 16.04. Uninstall the existing Nvidia proprietary graphics driver. To remove all the proprietary nvidia packages run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove  
sudo reboot
```

Remove the PPA that you used to install the Nvidia 430 driver from your software sources (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) if that PPA is still there, run `sudo apt update` and then run the following commands from the terminal.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-384  
sudo reboot
```

Then fix the login loop by following the instructions in the answers to [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/). If that doesn't fix the login loop, follow steps 5 and 6 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059366/restart-loop-after-nvidia-zotac-card-install/1059367#1059367).

Comment: So the sources.list contains 
`graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list,        teamviewer.list, 
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save,   teamviewer.list.save`. Shall I delete both PPA-related?

Comment: These two lines should be deleted: from sources.list: `graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` and `graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save`. Then run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software. The two teamviewer lines look OK.

Comment: Ok. But now when trying to install the driver it is unable to locate it. `ubuntu-drivers list` now gives me no available drivers, so how to download and install it? Bear in mind my Ubuntu version is 16.04.6.

Comment: The Nvidia driver for 16.04 is *nvidia-384* which I edited in my answer. If nvidia-384 doesn't work then try nvidia-current.

Comment: I have to add the repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers` before installing the driver. But yet it's probably not the correct one since it is rebooting in a low resolution login screen and is slow. I will try various other versions and see if I can get it right.

Comment: Try either nvidia-340 or nvidia-currrent. I've used nvidia-340 in 16.04 and it's good.

Comment: Neither works. Just keep getting the same slow low-res login screen that doesn't let me login. At this point I am thinking of getting rid of Linux...